# Cycle2 make images links

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, cycle

Hi Ive just swapped from Keyframes to Cycle2 (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) as a way of slideshowing images , I swapped to cycle2 as i believed this would allow me to make the images links , I only need one of the images to a link not all of them so when the slideshow gets to the slide the link is active ,

```
 <img src="/images/promo1.jpg">
 <img src="/images/promo2.jpg">
 <img src="/images/promo3.jpg">
 <img src="/images/promo4.jpg">
```

this works fine slideshows perfect, soon at i try

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk">
 <img src="images/promo2.jpg"></a>
```

on just one of the images , it knocks it out of the slideshow and displays it underneath as its own image.

any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the Cycle2 FAQ](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/faq/)

> ## I want to use slides that are not images. How do I tell Cycle2 what my slides are?
>
> Use the data-cycle-slides attribute to provide a jQuery selector which
>   identifies the elements within the container that are slides. For
>   example, if your slideshow is a ul with li slides you would set the
>   attribute like this: data-cycle-slides="li"

```
<ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="li">
    <li><img src="path/to/some/image1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="path/to/some/image2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="path/to/some/image3.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

In your case, you probably need something like:

```
<ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="li" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz">
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><h2>This is a non-image slide</h2></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com"><h2>This is a non-image slide</h2></a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZV9L/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

it would be correct specify the protocol - "http://"

```
<ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="li">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk"><img src="path/to/some/image1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk"><img src="path/to/some/image2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk"><img src="path/to/some/image3.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please remove this ANSWER and post your correction suggestion as a comment under [apaul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16485594/517705). If you don't want to get more downvotes.